# Indexing without knowing the index of a row, only the title of the row index

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, indexing

I'm currently following Python Crash Course book, and one task from  Chapter 16 is to make part of my code able to go through csv's and read the high and low temperatures of locations. The example code gives the python the index `TMAX` and `TMIN`, but they are different indexes in each csv.

The try it yourself section says to edit the code so that it can read either csv without specified index.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

filename = 'data/death_valley_2018_simple.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    dates, highs, lows = [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
    try:
        high = int(row[4])
        low = int(row[5])
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Missing data for {current_date}")
    else:
        dates.append(current_date)
        highs.append(high)
        lows.append(low)

# Plot the high and low temps.
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, highs, c='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(dates, lows, c='blue', alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(dates, highs, lows, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.1)
ax.axis([17520, 17911, 20, 130])

# Format plot.
title = "Daily high and low temps - 2018\nDeath Valley, CA"
ax.set_title(title, fontsize=20)
ax.set_xlabel('', fontsize=16)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize=16)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)

plt.show()
```

You can see `high = int(row[4])`, which in the csv file is `TMAX`, how do I tell python to find the index with `"TMAX"` and `"TMIN"` while looping through rows and taking a string and converting it to an integer from that index, allowing this program to find the index by itself by searching for the title and using the index of that title. I tried `variable.index("TMAX")` which returned 4 and the graph didn't print out the data from the csv. I tried various other ways of trying to tell python to only use data from the index without giving the index number.

```
"STATION","NAME","DATE","PRCP","TMAX","TMIN","TOBS"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-01","0.00","65","34","42"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-02","0.00","61","38","46"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-03","0.00","69","34","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-04","0.00","69","39","48"
```

and for reference, another csv with `TMAX` and `TMIN` at different index locations:

```
"STATION","NAME","DATE","PRCP","TAVG","TMAX","TMIN"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-01","0.45",,"48","38"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-02","0.56",,"48","43"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-03","0.40",,"46","41"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-04","0.99",,"42","40"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-05","0.25",,"46","38"
"USW00025333","SITKA AIRPORT, AK US","2018-01-06","0.46",,"44","37"
```

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of Python Crash Course. If it helps for any future questions, the solutions to most exercises are available [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/solutions/).

Comment: @japhyr, was this located where I would have found the resources also? not sure why I missed it if so. Excellent book btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *I tried `variable.index("TMAX")` which returned 4 and the graph didn't print out the data from the csv.*
- It's not evident where the line of code is placed in the attempt
- Given the existing code from the example
- [GitHub: death_valley_2018_full.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/master/chapter_16/the_csv_file_format/data/death_valley_2018_full.csv)
- [GitHub: death_valley_highs_lows.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/master/chapter_16/the_csv_file_format/death_valley_highs_lows.py)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`**

```py
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    idxh = header_row.index('TMAX')  # determine index for TMAX
    idxl = header_row.index('TMIN')  # determine index for TMIN

    # Get dates, and high and low temperatures from this file.
    dates, highs, lows = [], [], []
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%Y-%m-%d')

        try:
            high = int(row[idxh])  # use the new variable in place of hardcoded index
            low = int(row[idxl])  # use the new variable in place of hardcoded index
        ...  # remainder of the code from the example: nothing was changed
```

[image]

- Most of the data, incase the repo goes away

```py
"STATION","NAME","DATE","PRCP","SNOW","SNWD","TMAX","TMIN","TOBS"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","65","34","42"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","61","38","46"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","34","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","39","48"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","40","57"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","47","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","54","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-08","0.07","0.0","0.0","62","52","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-09","0.40","0.0","0.0","60","51","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","64","49","50"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","67","45","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","68","44","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","45","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","72","44","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","46","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","70","49","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","71","47","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","71","46","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-19","0.01","0.0","0.0","78","48","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","68","54","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","46","47"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","66","39","45"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","37","46"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","37","47"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","75","42","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","42","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","38","50"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","44","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","48","61"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","48","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-01-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","78","44","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","45","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","45","59"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","46","59"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","87","57","61"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","85","47","63"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","88","51","70"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","83","53","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","85","48","57"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","82","46","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","82","48","62"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","49","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","70","47","57"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","72","54","57"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","50","58"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","48","63"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","53","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","42","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","41","66"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","66","46","46"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","62","38","45"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","65","39","48"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","67","37","49"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","64","40","43"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","60","38","45"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","70","42","47"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-26","0.05","0.0","0.0","69","36","62"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","62","44","45"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-02-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","69","38","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","47","62"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","61","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","52","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","70","44","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","72","47","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","48","59"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","75","48","50"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","80","41","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","83","48","63"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-10","0.04","0.0","0.0","80","58","59"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-11","0.08","0.0","0.0","82","58","67"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","85","58","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","90","59","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","80","64","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","56","64"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","55","63"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","55","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","47","61"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","49","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","52","68"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","83","58","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-22","0.03","0.0","0.0","79","66","67"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","84","59","67"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","63","63"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","57","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","56","64"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","84","59","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","70","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","68","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","68","78"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-03-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","99","65","84"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","66","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","90","69","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","72","74"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","61","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","70","85"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","98","76","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","100","77","79"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","65","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","69","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","64","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","80","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","83","67","68"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","86","59","69"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","64","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","64","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","82","59","59"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","54","66"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","87","54","74"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","78","62","67"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","59","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","99","67","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","68","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","76","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","105","73","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","106","70","85"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","73","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","80","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","70","79"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","71","74"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-04-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","85","65","73"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","84","60","60"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","82","59","73"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","63","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","102","66","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","105","72","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","77","92"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","82","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","77","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","116","82","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","79","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","78","78"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","69","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","71","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","74","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","100","72","85"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","101","79","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","69","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","102","75","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","105","82","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","81","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","81","82"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","100","76","86"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","80","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","83","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","75","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","70","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","102","74","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","79","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","84","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","89","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-05-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","101","81","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","71","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","82","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","118","79","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","87","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","114","88","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","88","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","85","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","81","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","88","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","106","85","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","78","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","82","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","95","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","90","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","112","92","92"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","85","86"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","101","78","82"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","75","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","79","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","118","87","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","126","94","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","96","100"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","92","100"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","92","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","97","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","96","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","94","100"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","116","89","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","86","97"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-06-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","118","88","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","118","89","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","96","100"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","94","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","90","97"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","89","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","82","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","94","108"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","126","96","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-09","0.03","0.0","0.0","121","103","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-10","0.01","0.0","0.0","114","94","97"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","94","99"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-12","0.01","0.0","0.0","115","86","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","114","86","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","97","106"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","99","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","124","96","108"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","123","102","109"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","103","109"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","101","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","93","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","115","96","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","93","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","125","96","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","127","95","111"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","127","102","109"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","127","100","110"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","127","94","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","124","101","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","124","100","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","123","103","107"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-07-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","103","104"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","96","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","97","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","98","104"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","97","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","88","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","85","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","121","80","97"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","122","85","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","122","90","106"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","98","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","97","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","112","93","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","94","105"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","118","95","102"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","95","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","95","100"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","116","93","104"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","97","104"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","122","92","104"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","119","99","103"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","117","96","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","115","92","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","115","91","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","88","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","88","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","114","87","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","86","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","83","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","112","88","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","91","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-08-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","83","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","83","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","78","101"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","113","89","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","112","87","95"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","84","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","114","82","98"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","115","85","99"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","120","83","99"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","116","88","96"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","87","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","84","93"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","85","93"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","78","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","82","91"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","84","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","78","92"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","76","92"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","106","74","86"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","71","84"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","107","77","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","71","86"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","74","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","85","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","108","77","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","111","79","86"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","109","78","85"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","69","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","110","70","94"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","105","86","88"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-09-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","103","82","90"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","104","86","89"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","101","86","87"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","81","81"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","75","79"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","73","83"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-06","0.07","0.0","0.0","94","73","74"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","87","72","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","69","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","92","63","78"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","68","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","70","79"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","72","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","66","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","89","68","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","86","61","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","68","73"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","90","58","69"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","58","68"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","56","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","72","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","70","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-22","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","69","77"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-23","0.00","0.0","0.0","97","64","79"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-24","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","64","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-25","0.00","0.0","0.0","96","63","73"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-26","0.00","0.0","0.0","95","61","75"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-27","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","59","71"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-28","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","59","74"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-29","0.00","0.0","0.0","94","59","80"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-30","0.00","0.0","0.0","85","71","72"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-10-31","0.00","0.0","0.0","83","61","61"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-01","0.00","0.0","0.0","89","57","82"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","90","60","68"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-03","0.00","0.0","0.0","93","56","82"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-04","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","69","70"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-05","0.00","0.0","0.0","90","55","69"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-06","0.00","0.0","0.0","91","57","65"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-07","0.00","0.0","0.0","86","51","76"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-08","0.00","0.0","0.0","79","64","64"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-09","0.00","0.0","0.0","81","56","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","39","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","44","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","48","50"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-13","0.00","0.0","0.0","73","43","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","45","49"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-15","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","42","54"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-16","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","42","52"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-17","0.00","0.0","0.0","75","41","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-18","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","41","53"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-19","0.00","0.0","0.0","72","42","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-20","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","44","48"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-11-21","0.00","0.0","0.0","74","40","56"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-02","0.00","0.0","0.0","68","49","49"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-10","0.00","0.0","0.0","67","45","51"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-11","0.00","0.0","0.0","76","42","55"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-12","0.00","0.0","0.0","77","43","58"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-13","0.00",,,"72","46","50"
"USC00042319","DEATH VALLEY, CA US","2018-12-14","0.00","0.0","0.0","63","40","47"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Mike You're welcome, glad this worked for you.